# RequireJS : Can I use require() instead of define()

Tags: requirejs

Suppose there are three modules: *m1*, *m2*, *m3*

Where *mi*(i=1..3) is empty module:

```
define(function() {
    return this;
})
```

And exists additional module *useAll* that depends on *m1*, *m2*, *m3* modules.

What is the difference between two implementations of useAll module:

1. All modules on which depends useAll mentioned in define()

   define(['*m1*', '*m2*', '*m3*'], function() {...})
2. Modules mentioned in require() function

   define(function () {
       require(['*m1*']);
       require(['*m2*']);
       require(['*m3*']);
       ...
   })

Is there any issues with script loading time and order?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. The diferrence is that in the second implementation your
   `require` are treated by `r.js` as nested dependencies and
   by default they will not get included in optimization process,
   unless you specify:

   [findNestedDependencies](https://github.com/jrburke/r.js/blob/master/build/example.build.js#L328)
   : true

   From the docs:

   > Finds require() dependencies inside a require() or define call. By
   >   default this value is false, because those resources should be
   >   considered dynamic/runtime calls. However, for some optimization
   >   scenarios, it is desirable to include them in the build.
2. Another difference, is that the second implementation can load
   CommonJs modules too.
3. If you use `require` to define your module, you cannot return any value as a result of execution. This means, that you cannot use this module as a real dependency to another module